# Change background color of indent in VSCODE?

Tags: fortran, themes, visual-studio-code

I am translating the theme from my favorite FORTRAN editor (now defunct) to VSCODE. So far so good. The one thing I can't seem to locate is how to colorize the background of first 6 columns and only when the line has data.

defunct editor:
[image]

my VSCODE theme:
[image]

Is it possible to do this in a theme or will that have to go into an extension?

Comment: This is the 21st century calling - haven't you heard of free source form ?  :-)

Comment: Have no idea what that means. I am using VS Code.

Comment: Free form is the aource form, typically in .f90 files, where you do not care about first 6 columns. It has been around for almost 30 years.

Comment: Thats all great info...but it doesn't help me with VSCode.